# Does Apple Pay work on Apple Watch if not connected to phone/cellular?

Tags: apple-watch, apple-pay

If I don't have my phone on me, and it has nothing to connect to, would I still be able to make payments with just my watch?

I have an Apple Watch series 4 (no cellular)

Comment: Did it work when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205547).

Per Apple, you can still do many things even if your Watch isn't connected to your iPhone, cellular, or wifi.

Thanks to @grg's comment for pointing out that the Watch uses NFC to make a connection to the payment terminal.

Comment: This is the right answer, but Bluetooth is not involved with payment terminal & Apple Watch communication which uses NFC: https://support.apple.com/guide/security/seccb53a35f0/web

Comment: Thanks @grg, i've updated my answer.